# Pandas groupby: compute (relative) sizes and save in original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

my database structure is such that I have units, that belong to several groups and have different variables (I focus on one, X, for this question). Then we have year-based records. So the database then looks like

```
    unitid, groupid, year, X
0        1        1, 1990, 5
1        2        1, 1990, 2
2        2        1, 1991, 3
3        3        2, 1990, 10
```

etc. Now what I would like to do is measure some "intensity" variable, that is going to be the number of units per group and year, and I would like to put it back into the database.

So far, I am doing

```
asd = df.drop_duplicates(cols=['unitid', 'year'])
groups = asd.groupby(['year', 'groupid'])
intensity = groups.size()
```

And intensity then looks like

```
year groupid
1961    2000    4
        2030    3
        2040    1
        2221    1
        2300    2
```

However, I don't know how to put them back into the old dataframe. I can access them through `intensity[0]`, but `intensity.loc()` gives a LocIndexer not callable error.

Secondly, it would be very nice if I could scale intensity. Instead of "units per group-year", it would be "units per group-year, scaled by average/max units per group-year in that year". If {t,g} denotes a group-year cell, that would be:

[image: relative intensity]

That is, if my simple intensity variable (for time and group) is called intensity(t, g), I would like to create `relativeIntensity(t,g) = intensity(t,g)/mean(intensity(t=t,g=:))` - if this fake code helps at all making myself clear.

Thanks!

**Update**

Just putting the answer here (explicitly) for readability. The first part was solved by

```
intensity = intensity.reset_index()
df['intensity'] = intensity[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, days later, I found out that the first answer to this double question was wrong. Perhaps someone can elaborate to what `.size()` actually does, but this is just in case someone googles this question does not follow my wrong path.

It turned out that `.size()` had way less rows than the original object (also if I used `reset_index()`, and however I tried to stack the sizes back into the original object, there were a lot of rows left with `NaN`. The following, however, works

```
groups = asd.groupby(['year', 'groupid'])
intensity = groups.apply(lambda x: len(x))
asd.set_index(['year', 'groupid'], inplace=True)
asd['intensity'] = intensity
```

Alternatively, one can do

```
groups = asd.groupby(['fyearq' , 'sic'])
# change index to save groupby-results
asd= asd.set_index(['fyearq', 'sic'])
asd['competition'] = groups.size()
```

And the second part of my question is answered through

```
# relativeSize
def computeMeanInt(group):
    group = group.reset_index()
    # every group has exactly one weight in the mean:
    sectors = group.drop_duplicates(cols=['group'])
    n = len(sectors)
    val = sum(sectors.competition)
    return float(val) / n


result = asd.groupby(level=0).apply(computeMeanInt)
asd= asd.reset_index().set_index('fyearq')
asd['meanIntensity'] = result
# if you don't reset index, everything crashes (too intensive, bug, whatever)
asd.reset_index(inplace=True)
asd['relativeIntensity'] = asd['intensity']/asd['meanIntensity']
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [a multi-index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex). You can reset the index by calling `.reset_index()` to your resultant dataframe. Or you can disable it when you compute the group-by operation, by specifying `as_index=False` to the `groupby()`, like:

```
intensity = asd.groupby(["year", "groupid"], as_index=False).size()
```

As to your second question, I'm not sure what you mean in `Instead of "units per group-year", it would be "units per group-year, scaled by average/max units per group-year in that year".`. If you want to compute "intensity" by `intensity / mean(intensity)`, you can use the `transform` method, like:

```
asd.groupby(["year", "groupid"])["X"].transform(lambda x: x/mean(x))
```

Is this what you're looking for?

#### Update

If you want to compute `intensity / mean(intensity)`, where `mean(intensity)` is based only on the `year` and not `year/groupid` subsets, then you first have to create the `mean(intensity)` based on the `year` only, like:

```
intensity["mean_intensity_only_by_year"] = intensity.groupby(["year"])["X"].transform(mean)
```

And then compute the `intensity / mean(intensity)` for all `year/groupid` subset, where the `mean(intensity)` is derived only from `year` subset:

```
intensity["relativeIntensity"] = intensity.groupby(["year", "groupid"]).apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(
                        {"relativeIntensity": x["X"] / x["mean_intensity_only_by_year"] }
                    ))
```

Maybe this is what you're looking for, right?

Comment: Quick feedback to the second part before I digest the first part: Almost. I want mean(x), but not the mean(x) taken over the whole dataset, but only mean(x) taken over data with the same year.

Comment: The `mean(x)` is computed based on the groups, not the whole dataset. So in this case each `mean(x)` is computed based on each `year/groupid` subsets.

Comment: Or maybe you want to compute it based on the `year` only, not on `year/groupid` combination?

Comment: Year only. This is supposed to be about "intensity", as in the first part of the question. I just noticed as well as for this (more urgent) question, I actually didn't need to introduce X - did that help?

Comment: Updated. As to the "intensity", I just got that it's about physics, but I have little or no knowledge in it...

Comment: You misunderstand something: "intensity" is the outcome of the first part. It is the number of (unique) units in the group-year box.

And this then makes the mean difficult. Because I don't want a mean weighted by "number of units per year", I need it weighted by "number of groups per year".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51182/discussion-between-foobar-and-gardecolo)